# Showing that if a distribution is symmetric, then its median is the point of symmetry

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to show that if a distribution function is symmetric, then its median is the point of symmetry. I think it is very simple but here is what I have come up with so far:

Let $f_X(x)$ be a symmetric function about point $a$. Then, $f_X(a+x) = f_X(a-x)$ for all $x$.

I need to show that $\int_{-\infty}^af_X(x)dx = \int_{a}^\infty f_X(x)dx$ (definition of median).

So:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^af_X(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^0f_X(a+x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^0f_X(a-x)dx = \int_{0}^\infty f_X(a+x)dx = \int_{a}^\infty f_X(x)dx.
\end{align}

Can someone help me check if it is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: Actually I have just realized that $x$ would have to be greater than $0$ using this definition. I think I need to change variables here.

Answer (score 1):

The proof presented in the question is fine, and is (more or less) the proof that I present to first-year calculus students.  For completeness, the result presented in calculus is

> **Theorem:** If
>
> - $f$ is symmetric about $a$ (i.e. $f(a+x) = f(a-x)$ for all $x$), and
> - the integral $\int_{a}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ exists,
>
> then
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x. $$

Because I like things that are centered at zero, the proof that I tend to show students is for even functions (i.e. functions which satisfy the above properties with $a=0$).  So suppose that $g(x) = g(-x)$ for all $x$.  Then
\begin{align*} \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{-\infty} -g(-t)\,\mathrm{d}t && \text{(CoV:  $t=-x$, hence $\mathrm{d}x = -\mathrm{d}t$)} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} g(-t)\,\mathrm{d}t && \text{($\textstyle-\int_{b}^{a} = \int_{a}^{b}$)} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} g(t)\,\mathrm{d}t && \text{($g$ is symmetric about $0$)} \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, && \text{(rename the variable, for giggles)}
\end{align*}
which is the desired result.  The more general proof follows by observing that if $f$ is symmetric about $a$, then the function $g$, defined by
$$ g(x) = f(x+a) $$
(the left translation of $f$ by $a$ units) is symmetric about $0$.  The original result is then obtained by making the change of variables $x \mapsto x-a$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Indeed.  A typo. Like I said:  left-translation by $a$. :/

Answer (score 1):

You have assumed that your distribution has a probability density, i.e. is absolutely continuous.  If so, your approach is reasonable.

Here is a more general alternative just using the symmetry $P(X \le a)=P(X \ge a)$.

- $P(X <a)+P(X=a)+P(X>a)=1$ since exactly one of these events occurs
- so $2 P(X \le a)=2 P(X \ge a)= P(X \le a)+P(X \ge a)= 1+P(X=a)\ge 1$
- so $P(X \le a)\ge \frac12$ and $P(X \ge a)\ge \frac12$
- i.e. $a$ is a median of the distribution of $X$.